# Interrupt starting of an activity

Tags: android

This is probably a trivial question for experienced devs, but since I'm comming from PHP I'm struggling with the following problem:

I'm starting an activity. First thing it does ( in onCreate() ) is checking if a network connection is available. If not, I'm showing a dialog. So far it's working. However, in that case, I'd like to stop the startup-routine (onCreate, onResume, ...). How can I do that?

I've now changed my approach to putting everything in try/catch constructs, but many functions throw the same IOException error - how can I distinguish and show the appropriate message/dialog ? (eg: no wifi/3g available, no http connection possible, downloaded file is empty etc) ?

I've looked for tutorials but haven't found any that go more in detail but the obvious "try/catch" explanation...

Comment: It would be better if you post your code.

Comment: why do you want to do that? Please explain more about the thing why you want to stop the activity life-cycle.

Comment: Could you be more specific or post some code? As far as I understand you are trying to display specific messages for no-wifi, connection timeout etc...for this you must create specific methods: ex: isWifiEnabled() that return a boolean, there you check in Connectivity Manager if wifi in enabled etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move code from onCreate() to separate method ex. `init()` . Test network connection in onCreate(), when passed invoke `init()`, if not - `finish()`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(isConnectionAvailable()){
        init();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
}


public boolean isConnectionAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager manager           = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo         activeNetworkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return (activeNetworkInfo != null) && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Comment: thanks - a valid solution for the mini-problem. But overall, I'm still struggling with how to handle exceptions. My procedure contains eg the following steps: 1) convert str to url 2) open http connection to url 3) download text from the connection 4) convert downloaded text to JSON object 5) loop throught JSON object and output contents in textview. Every single step can throw exceptions (url invalid, server not reachable, downloaded text is empty etc). should I just put all of those steps in many nested "if"s ? Or should I try to catch exceptions (and where) ?

Comment: This is a question how to handle exceptions in java. This should help: [Best Practices for Exception Handling](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/exceptions.html). If I were you. 1. Check connection in `onCreate()` - show dialog when not connected. 2. Connection and parsing is long running task. I would do it in AsyncTask. In case of exception show dialog with message and `finish()` or try to recover - it depends on you. It's important to show descriptive error message when it's occured.

Answer (score 0):

```
After checking connection , if you have not net connection ,then finish() 
your activity so it will stop further process automatically
```

[For Checking all connection See my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908137/crash-when-is-no-internet-connection/9908476#9908476)

Comment: I'd rather show a Dialog first ... I'm calling finish() from the onClick of the OK button of that dialog.

Comment: yes it can be in that way also,if you got any help from my answer then accept it and up vote it

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to check this before you start your `Activity` or you can call `finish()` on your `Activity` if you don't have internet connection.